# How to simplify large tensor expressions with SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy, physics, symbolic-math

I'm trying to compute the Ricci tensor for the Kerr metric in Boyer-Lindquist coordinates. The calculation involves constructing several intermediate tensors including the Christoffel symbols of both kinds and the Riemmann tensor. Unfortunately, the tensor components get very complicated, and sympy doesn't simplify the Ricci tensor components to zero (which is what they should be). Here's the full code, however all you need to know is that the output is correct but not simplified.

```
from sympy import *
t,r,theta,phi=symbols('t r theta phi', real=True)

#list of coordinates
Xu=Array([t,r,T,P])  

#Kerr parameters
M,a=symbols('M a', real=True, positive=True)


#takes in a second-rank tensor (input as a an array), converts it to a matrix, calculates the inverse and returns it as an array object
def Inverse(gll):  
    gllMat=Matrix(gll)
    guu=simplify(gllMat.inv())
    return Array(guu)

#constructs the Kerr metric in Boyer-Lindquist coordinates, low-low form
def GetKerrgll(M,a,r,theta):
 kerrgll=Array([[-1+2*M*r/(a**2*cos(theta)**2+r**2),0,0,-2*a*M*r*sin(theta)**2/(r**2+a**2*cos(theta)**2)],
    [0, (a**2*cos(theta)**2+r**2)/(a**2-2*M*r+r**2),0,0],
    [0,0,a**2*cos(theta)**2+r**2,0],
    [-2*a*M*r*sin(theta)**2/(r**2+a**2*cos(theta)**2),0,0,(sin(theta)**2*((a**2+r**2)**2-a**2*(a**2-2*M*r+r**2)*sin(theta)**2))/(a**2*cos(theta)**2+r**2)]])    
    return nsimplify(kerrgll)

#Christoffel Connection of the first kind in low-low-low index form
def GetCClll(gll,X):  
    Dim=len(X)
    CClllout=[[[0 for b in range(Dim)] for u in range(Dim)] for v in range(Dim)]
    for b in range(Dim):
        for u in range(Dim):
            for v in range(Dim):
                CClllout[b][u][v]=Mul(S(1)/2,(diff(gll[b][u],X[v])+diff(gll[b][v],X[u])-diff(gll[u][v],X[b])))
    return Array(CClllout)

#Christoffel Connection of the second kind, up-low-low form
def GetCCull(gll,X):  
    Dim=len(X)
    guu=Inverse(gll)
    CClllin=GetCClll(gll,X)
    CCull=tensorcontraction(tensorproduct(guu, CClllin),(0,2)) #contraction of first and third indices of the fifth-rank tensor product g^{\alpha\rho} \Gamma_{\sigma\mu\nu} 
    return nsimplify(CCull)
                           
#Riemann tensor in up-low-low-low form
def GetRiemann(gll,X): 
    Dim=len(X)
    CCull=GetCCull(gll,X)
    Rulllout=[[[[0 for a in range(Dim)] for p in range(Dim)] for g in range(Dim)] for b in range(Dim)] #empty array with four indices
    for a in range(Dim):
        for p in range(Dim):
            for g in range(Dim):
                for b in range(Dim):
                    Rulllout[a][p][g][b]=simplify(diff(CCull[a][b][p],X[g])-diff(CCull[a][g][p],X[b])+sum(CCull[a][g][s]*CCull[s][b][p] for s in range(Dim))-sum(CCull[a][b][s]*CCull[s][g][p] for s in range(Dim)))
    return Array(Rulllout)
 
#Ricci tensor in low-low form           
def GetRicci(gll,X): 
    Rulll=GetRiemann(gll, X)
    Rll=tensorcontraction(Rulll,(0,2))
    return Rll

#print Ricci tensor
kerrgll=Getkerrgll(M,a,r,theta)
GetRicci(kerrgll,Xu)
```

The ouptut is correct and sufficiently simplified for manifolds such as flat spacetime and the surface of a sphere. But for Kerr spacetime my Ricci tensor components are hideous expressions instead of zero. How should I approach this?

I've tried simplification methods such as simplify(), nsimplify(), ratsimp(), and trigsimp() at various stages of the calculation with no luck. Also tried delaying evaluation of each term until the end.

The expressions start looking complicated when I compute the inverse of the Kerr metric, `Inverse(kerrgll)`, so maybe the issue starts there.

Comment: The code as shown does not run

Comment: If you use `from sympy.simplify.fu import TR5` then you might find that something like `TR5(expr.expand(numer=True)).expand(numer=True).factor()` is a better simplification routine than the ones you are using.